# How to unmute the master control?

Tags: java, audio, system

I've been attempting to unmute the computer by using a simple java application. However, when I try to do something like:

```
final Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(Port.Info.SPEAKER);
line.open();
BooleanControl muteControl = (BooleanControl) line.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
muteControl.setValue(false);
```

It does not work. Can anyone lead me in the right direction/
Thanks,
-Jaccob.

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you tried looking up other ways to do it, or are you trying to do it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

`Line` doesn't provide a setter for this property, you just can't turn on/off the main line that way AFAIK.

IMHO it's may be better that way: I don't know what app you're writing, but as a user, I hate when an application plays with my speaker ^^